# Serve Error Pages Using Apache HTTP Server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, apache2, mod-proxy

I am using Tomcat for hosting my web application and apache http server on top of it using mod proxy for load balancing.

When my application throws a 404 or 500 error, I want to serve the error pages through apache http server rather than tomcat server. This is because I am serving all of my static content through apache and don't want it as part of war. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the "ErrorDocument" directive in the virtualhost section of your apache config:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/my404page.html
ErrorDocument 500 /path/to/my500page.html
```

Additionally, since you're using mod proxy, you may you may wish to enable ProxyErrorOverride to let apache generate custom error documents for proxied content.

Also check out [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument)